# WSO2 MI - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/integrator/core/handler/RESTBasicAuthHandler

Tags: wso2, wso2-micro-integrator

I am migrating to WSO2 Micro Integrator 4.2.0 (latest version by today). The existing library i am using is throwing the following error: Failed! java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/wso2/carbon/integrator/core/handler/RESTBasicAuthHandler. The same library works fine using previous versions. What is the replacement of this class?

I am running the carbon application using Integration Studio latest version 8.2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the following handler.

```xml
<handlers>
    <handler class="org.wso2.micro.integrator.security.handler.RESTBasicAuthHandler"/>
</handlers>
```

If you want to do Authentication + Authorization you can use [this](https://github.com/yasassri/wso2mi-authorization-handler) custom handler.